# Create ObjectId from a Property value

Tags: mongodb, lookup, objectid

I am working with pipeline aggregation and want to perform chain of lookups between collections. I have _id in the documents as ObjectId and not strings. Now, when my first lookup in the pipeline executes, the result of ids is String and not Object IDs. Because of this my next lookup in the pipeline is failing. I read that there are issues in Mongo DB to perform lookups in such a situation. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781

To get around this, I am wondering if I can cast or create ObjectId using a property value such that my lookup can succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `new ObjectId($variableFromPipeline)` in the next stage of pipeline.

Read about [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator in mongo.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. I has tried this but it complains that the variable (from pipeline) is not defined.